# Cython initialization of object references

Tags: reference, cython

I'm trying to get a reference to a object in cython.
The following code compiles without problems:

```
cdef vector[int] a
a.push_back(1)
cdef vector[int] & b=a
```

However, as I add the following line:

```
b.push_back(1)
```

The compiler complains that b has been declared as a reference but not initialized.
How should I initialise a reference in cython? 
(the documentation is a bit vague on the usage of references in cython)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not doing this :

```
cdef vector[int] a
a.push_back(1)
cdef vector[int] *b=&a
b[0].push_back(1)
b.push_back(2)      # Works too, I gess
```

Comment: Because it complicates the code. I guess that's what we have that works right now. Thanks.